# Blend 4 DLL not found on TFS Build

Tags: dll, tfs, build, blend

i am trying to Build a project on our TFS server. The project uses the System.Windows.Interactivity DLL from Blend 4. But i cannot get the TFS server to find the DLL during Build

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1360,9): 
warning MSB3245: Dieser Verweis konnte nicht aufgelöst werden. Die System.Windows.Interactivity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL-Assembly wurde nicht gefunden.
```

I installed the Blend 4 SDK, the DLL ist installed in the same location as on my pc with the correct public key token:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\.NETFramework\v4.0\Libraries>sn -T System.Windows.Interactivity.dll

Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Strong Name Utility  Version 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Public key token is 31bf3856ad364e35
```

Reference in project file:

```
<Reference Include="System.Windows.Interactivity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
```

I rebooted the server already but no changes. Anybody an idea what i am missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

M.Radwan's approach would work, but I'd recommend copying those files into a "references" folder for your solution and checking them into version control. That will work for all of your teammates as well as any build machine you end up using. It will also ensure that everyone is using the same version of the assembly.

Comment: This should be done for all referenced assemblies that are not part of the SDKs.

Comment: Also, you'll need to change any references to the DLLs to point to the copy that is in your References folder. Note that these files will also need to be installed with your application. (unless you also plan on requiring the SDK to be installed separately) The DLLs will be included in your build output. This avoids the "It works on my machine" problem, as it will ensure it will work on all machines.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy the dlls to the common folder

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies

on the build server

Thanks
M.Radwan

Answer (score 0):

I ended up reinstalling Visual Studio on the TFS Server. After that the Blend SDK was installed and used correctly